# What is the internal structure of a Windows shortcut?

Tags: windows, hex, structure, shortcut

3 HDD in one computer: 2 with Windows XP, 1 with Windows 7, sequentially load the operating system from each of them.

I discover that some working shortcuts (not all) which created in first XP don't work in second XP and Windows 7 (not available for viewing the object for the shortcut).

To understand why it's don't work I create the same shortcut in windows 7 and open both files of these shorcuts in hex editor.

I discover that it's structures is diffrent but I do not know how to compare it.

What is the internal structure of a Windows shortcut?

What start and end bytes of some usefull blocks of shortcut's content?

Comment: I dont think that this is the right place for such questions. what do you mean sequentially load the OS?

Comment: @Skaros Ilias - it's means that I start one of them, then shutdown, after start next OS, then shutdown, then start third OS, and in each of them was accessible all 3 hdd, problem shortcuts was accessible in other OSs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shortcut (*.lnk*) file format information can be found at [[MS.Docs]: [MS-SHLLINK]: Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943).

However, to spare you from reading that whole *.pdf*, one thing that is stored within a shortcut for sure (can be checked by "looking" at the shortcut using a hex viewer) is the (full) target path that it references (**!!!important!!!** at creation time): so it's *"**DriveLetter:**\the_full_path"*.

To clear up confusion, I'd suggest playing with shortcuts that have targets on the same drive.

When switching *HDD*s, the **DriveLetter**s (aka *"C:"*) point to different things:

- Let's say that you created on one of them a shortcut: *"C:\shortcut.lnk"* (*"C:"* is the **DriveLetter** assigned to the *HDD* where *Win* booted from): let's call this *HDD1*. 
  The shortcut points to target file located on another *HDD* (and partition): let's call this *HDD2* (e.g. *"E:\target.txt*)
- When you'll switch *HDD*s (making *HDD2* primary boot disk) the **DriveLetter**s will change too, so now:

  - ***HDD2*** will be ***"C:"***
  - ***HDD1*** will be ***"D:"***

  Things complicate even more when introducing *HDD3* and so on.

As an answer to our question: the *.lnk* files don't work because their target is no longer present.

Comment: thank you very much for great answer, I will read this document, I can only add that some of the problematic shortcuts were on the network resources and they were available

Comment: Hmm, the network resources how were they available (in the form of _remote mounted drives_ or simply _file shares_ )? This is important and the network customizations on each Win installation (on each of the 3 HDDs). If i understood correctly, the shortcuts from 1st XP are the problem, there's where you should look for (before reading that whole PDF).

Comment: File shares, all computers in the domain (if loaded from some OS, computer is domain computer), when I opened problematic shortcut from XP in hex editor, I saw path starting with two slashes \\ (e.g.\\some_domain\some_folder). Yes, problems with shortcuts from first XP (second XP I bring to show that problem not in XP in general but in current build). The initial task was in migration data from XP  to w7. Thanks one more time, I will try to analyze.

Comment: Ok, so the file paths in the shortcuts are referencing a simple _file share_ (as i asked in my prev comment)(at least on XP). That's perfectly OK (i created a shortcut from  'C:\some_path` to `D:\some_other_path`). The `\\servername\sharename\file (i might have slipped some chars)` is used to reference a different machine in the same network, with (one of its) shared folders.....

Comment: Can I ask you? I read about MS-SHLLINK, it says that in SHELL_LINK_HEADER after 4 bytes follows "LinkCLSID (16 bytes): A class identifier (CLSID). This value MUST be 00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046." But on windows 7 I open some working shortcuts in hex editor and discover in all of it value "01 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 46" then there is the difference in the first 4 bytes of this value. How to understand it? I checked registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\ProgID @ is really lnkfile

Comment: I've just created shortcuts on `XP` and `W7`  and on both the first 20 bytes are `4C 00 00 00 01 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 46` (hex) as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871375.aspx).

Comment: Oh, now I see the difference. If you look closely, the (4) bytes in the first group of the GUID are reversed `00 02 14 01` <-> `01 14 02 00`. I've seen this in other scenarios (for example sections of a motherboard's UUID are reversed), i don't know exactly why. I first thought it was because of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), but if it was because of that it should apply to all groups (and for `C0 00` doesn't).

Comment: thank you for your comment, I also thought at first about Endianness, because document says "Multi-byte data values in the Shell Link Binary File Format are stored in little-endian format.", but there are inverted only first 4 bytes, so  while it remains a mystery