# How to resolve shortcut to it's target path using windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am scanning through files in directory using:

```
CHAR mymask[] = "*";
WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;
HANDLE hSearch = FindFirstFile(mymask, &FileData);
if(hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    for(UINT i =0;;i++)
    {
        if(FileData.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
           && strcmp(FileData.cFileName,".")  != 0 && strcmp(FileData.cFileName,"..") != 0)
        {
            DoSomthWithSubdirectory(FileData.cFileName);
        }
        if (!FindNextFile(hSearch,&FileData))
            break;
    }
    FindClose(hSearch);
}
```

How can I process shortcuts being found in a directory in a similar manner: I need to call DoSomthWithSubdirectory(...) for their target paths as if they were ordinary directories.

Comment: Are you asking for *shortcuts* or *symbolic links* (or other file system redirection features)?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629914/what-is-the-internal-structure-of-a-windows-shortcut/30630750#30630750)'s something related to shortcuts (make sure you follow the _MSDN_ links).