# winapi create shortcut failed

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2012, shortcut

I want to create shortcut of a file. I found [this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891(v=vs.85).aspx#Shellink_Creating_Shortcut) that describe how to write this, and I copy that in my code to use.
But I have some problems, first it had the following error: "**CoInitialize has not been called.**"  I add this `CoInitialize(nullptr);` to solve the error, but I have error yet.

when I debug it, it has **"Information not available, no symbols loaded for windows.storage.dll"** error on this line:

```
hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl);
```

and after execution when I see the destination path, it creates a shortcut with the name but i can't open it, and it hasn't any content.

What wrong with this?

Does the error make this problem?

I'm using VS 2012.

**Code Edited:**

```
// #include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include "objbase.h"
#include "objidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR);

void wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[ ], wchar_t* envp[ ])
{

    WCHAR lpwSource[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    lstrcpyW(lpwSource, (LPCWSTR)argv[1]);

    WCHAR lpwDest[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    lstrcpyW(lpwDest, (LPCWSTR)argv[2]);

    HRESULT hResult = 0;
    hResult = CreateLink(lpwSource, lpwDest, NULL);

    if (hResult == S_OK) {

        printf("Shortcut was created successfully.\n");

    } else {

        printf("Shortcut creation failed.\n");

    }

    getchar();
}

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCWSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc)
{
    HRESULT hres = 0;
    IShellLink* psl;

    HRESULT hCoInit = 0;
    hCoInit = CoInitialize(nullptr);

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
        IPersistFile* ppf;

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj);
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc);

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(lpszPathLink, TRUE);
            ppf->Release();
        }
        psl->Release();
    }
    return hres;
}
```

Comment: This is really just another incarnation of the main theme, you seem to be having difficulty with: Character encodings. You are first converting UTF-16 to UTF-8, and then move on to convert that UTF-8 string as if it were ANSI encoding. You will solve *all* of those issues by reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Note that in this code, you do not even need to convert *anything*. Simply pass your UTF-16 character string to `CreateLink`.

Comment: What does that mean: "*but i can't open it, and it hasn't any content*"? Is the file created? What's its size? What are the arguments you pass to your executable? Have you tried with *ASCII* only chars? Check functions (e.g. `WideCharToMultiByte`) return codes and handle errors. `MultiByteToWideChar` doesn't seem to belong there (since you create the string with its counterpart). You are mixing codepages.

Comment: yes it create shortcut but when I open it (if main file is a photo) the photo viewer said "we can't open this file". its size is 560 bytes while main file size is 49 KB. I pass two arguments to it with command: they are main file path and shortcut file path that I want to save shortcut in it, same as following: `a.exe "D:\folder\test.png" "D:\folder\folder2\shortcut.png"`. No I didn't test ASCIIs because program should support strings in other languages. I edited my code. check it again and leave comment please. @CristiFati

Comment: @IInspectable Now check the code again and leave your comment please.

Comment: You **are** using only *ASCII* (in the example). It's OK to do so when debugging, as you don't want to introduce all kinds of unknowns in the mix. Ran your code (minor changes: got rid of some `#include`s) with *VStudio 2013* (closest version that I have to yours) and the shortcut was created and valid (pointing to the right file). How do you try opening it? You might want to use *"D:\folder\folder2\shortcut.png.lnk"* as it'a a **.lnk** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629914/what-is-the-internal-structure-of-a-windows-shortcut/30630750#30630750) **not** a **.png** (that viewer knows).

Comment: @CristiFati you are right. I edited question text and I added your answer.  you can add your answer below of question then I will accept it. thanks a lot.

Comment: Done. But **never** include an answer in a question (as the whole question would become pointless). Add an answer to it (there's nothing wrong answering your own question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I specified in my comment, I've built the code (previous version (*Question **VERSION #2.***) from the one at answer time - which *BTW* was containing some string conversions that would have most likely failed on non English locales) with *VStudio 2013* and ran it on my *Win 10* (English) machine. It created a valid shortcut.

So, there was nothing wrong with the code (in the sense that it wouldn't work). 
The problem was that the output file was also having the *.png* extension, and when opening it, *Win* would attempt to use the default image viewer / editor, which would treat the file as *PNG* (based on its extension). 
That is obviously wrong, as *.lnk* files have their own format (as I briefly explained in [[SO]: What is the internal structure of a Windows shortcut? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630750/4788546)).

The solution was to **properly name** the shortcut (let it have the *.lnk* extension).

Some additional (non critical) notes about the code (current state):

- No need for *C++ (11)* features (*nullptr* (also check next bullet)):

  ```c
  HRESULT hCoInit = CoInitialize(NULL);
  ```
- Reorganize the *#include*s. Use the following list:

  ```c
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <shobjidl.h>
  #include <shlguid.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  ```